Can't open file 'C:\\Users\\H\\Downloads\\Hossein-OH\\VSCODE\\main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I got this error today;
previously I didn't get that.
My python file is in "C:\Users\H\Downloads\Hossein-OH\VSCODE\PYTHON API\main.py"
and this is the documentation
from flask import Flask, Request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Home"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

I tried to run my code in VScode terminal with "python main.py"
but I got this error:

can't open file 'C:\Users\H\Downloads\Hossein-OH\VSCODE\main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory


I tried to run my code in VScode terminal with python main.py There is no main.py file in that directory.  It's as simple as that.

The reason might be the two paths you show do not match:

C:\Users\H\Downloads\Hossein-OH\VSCODE\PYTHONAPI\main.py
C:\Users\H\Downloads\Hossein-OH\VSCODE\main.py


why the PYTHON API folder is not recognized?
the first path is the file location
why when i run the "python main.py" the second path is shown?

@KereinDejohnwin Sorry, I don't know your setup well enough to answer that.

When you manually execute commands to run python scripts in the terminal, you need to check the folder path in the terminal.
I think when you execute the script, your terminal is at C:\Users\H\Downloads\Hossein-OH\VSCODE.
You need to execute command cd PYTHON API. So it can find the main.py file you need.
Another solution is to use Run Python File Command provided by Python extension.
You could open your Settings and search for Executr In File Dir then check it. It'll allow you run python script in the file's directory instead of the workspce.

Then use Run Python File button.


i already do that with Executr In File Dir. not working
when i run cd PYTHON API i get this error A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'API'.

not helpful but GPT said that you should execute command PYTHON API with Quotation  ( cd "PYTHON API" ) mark because PowerShell have a problem parsing folders with spaces or other...

In our custom, we use hump names and do not randomly add special symbols or Spaces in the file name, but when you try to remove the space does it solve the problem?

There are two scenarios:

You are inside in some sub-directory of "C:\Users\H\Downloads\Hossein-OH\VSCODE\PYTHON API", Suppose that you have created some \xyz directory inside \PYTHON API and on terminal you are inside that \xyz directory. And if you running your  main.py from that location then you will get that error.

You are inside in some of the directory and not in \PYTHON API and on terminal some C:\\Users\H\Downloads\Hossein-OH\VSCODE or else is showing and you are now running your flask server using python main.py then still you won't be able to execute it and get the error.


Solution:
You have to be in that directory or you should write down the path to that directory from your current path displaying on the terminal
**Explanation: **
Suppose on terminal it is showing "C:\Users\H\Downloads\Hossein-OH\VSCODE\PYTHON API\xyz" [i.e. you are currently on this path in terminal] and we know that the main.py is inside the \PYTHON API , in this case you have to go back using cd .. in terminal and then execute python main.py.
Suppose on terminal it is showing "C:\Users\H\Downloads\Hossein-OH" and in this case we have to type the full relative path to that \PYTHON API directory from the the path we are on in terminal. so we will execute the main.py file with python ./PYTHON API/main.py.  Actually this means , . dot means from current path go to PYTHON API and then in that start .py file.

in vscode when i select open a folder and select PYTHON API the showing path in terminal is correct... but when i open the folder VSCODE (i want to see all my projects) the terminal path is wrong
